# MySQL query to SQL-Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a mysql query that I have to convert to sql server syntax, I am novice and perhaps someone can help me. Here is my code:

```
SELECT id, nick, mobile, name, description, direction, date, image FROM mytable WHERE number=1 ORDER BY date desc LIMIT 1, 10;
```

Is there some tool to try sql server querys or some online converter

Thanks for all

Comment: `select top 10 ...` and remove the LIMIT

Comment: yes but if I want to put limit 15, 30?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL 2012, you have the rather [unwieldy syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx):

```
SELECT id, nick, mobile, name, description, direction, date, image 
FROM mytable WHERE number=1 
ORDER BY date desc 
OFFSET 100 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

For SQL 2005, you generally need to adopt a 2-step approach to pagination via a derived table, e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY date desc) As RowID,
      id, nick, mobile, name, description, direction, date, image
    FROM mytable 
    WHERE number=1 
) As RowResults
WHERE RowID BETWEEN 101 AND 106;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8ae3d/3)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED :**

```
select * FROM
(
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) as RowNumber , * FROM mytable 
) tmp
where tmp.RowNumber between 15 AND 30
```

Comment: Yes but if I want to put limit 15, 30 in order to 1,10 to only show from 15 to 30? thanks

Comment: I'll Update the answer